# Detect database type when running Entity Framework migration

Tags: entity-framework

Is it possible to detect the type of database (SQL, SQL CE, MySQL, etc.) that a migration is being executed against so that we can modify the custom sql statements?

Comment: You want a migration with a switch with different sql statements or a migration which contains only the specific statement for the type of the database?

Comment: You might want to access the ProviderName from your config file using [ConnectionStringSettingsCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.connectionstringsettingscollection(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: A migration with a switch with different sql statements for different databases would be ideal